# Assume that $A_{n} = (1,1,2,2,...,n,n)$, how to reorder these $2n$ numbers such that there are $k$ numbers between two $k$s

Tags: combinations

For example,

$n = 3$, $(2,3,1,2,1,3)$ or $(3,1,2,1,3,2)$

$n = 4$, $(4,1,3,1,2,4,3,2)$ or $(2,3,4,2,1,3,1,4)$

This problem does have a name, but I did not find it. Thanks for @Martin R, It is called Langford pairing problem.

Assume that $L_{n}$ is the number of solutions of Langford pairing problem.

Actually, I want to know some conclusions or references about the following:

1. The proof of $L_{n} = 0~~\text{iff}~~n~\text{mod}~4 = 1~\text{or}~2$.
2. The general formula or recurrence formula of $L_{n}$ (A176127$(n)$ in OEIS).
3. Given $n$, how to find one of the solutions.
4. Given $n$, how to find all the solutions and the representation of them.

As for (1), it is proved in ["Some new possibilities of optimum synthetic linear arrays for radioastronomy"](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1975A%26A....41..409B) in 1975. You are welcome if you have a simple proof.

As for (2)(4), the answer seems open.

As for (3), I have no idea about the algorithm.

Assume that $A_{m,n} = (1,2,\ldots,n,1,2,\ldots,n, \ldots, 1,2, \ldots, n)$ (repeat $m$ times).
There is a concept named high-order sequence denoted $L(m,n)$. It is denoted the number of permutations of $A_{m,n}$ with the property that there are $k$ numbers between each two $k$'s in the set for $k=1,\ldots,n$.

I will close this question unless it is useful.

Comment: Thought that https://oeis.org/A026272 might be relevant, but no luck.

Comment: It looks like youer second example is missing a $2$ in the end. What do you mean by "how to"? Do you want a prescription how to find such a reordering for general $n$?

Comment: You missed as well $(2,3,4,2,1,3,1,4)$ for the case of $n=2$,. indeed any valid arrangement when read forwards will also be a valid arrangement when read backwards.  A dirty javascript method reveals that there are no valid arrangements for $n=5$.  Running the same script for $n=6$ is taking a while, but I'm doubtful that any additional sequences will exist for higher $n$.  I might try rewriting it in python more efficiently if I get time.

Comment: There are no solutions for $n=5, 6$. There are $52$ solutions for $n=7$ and $300$ solutions for $n=8$. No solutions for $n=9, 10$, and $35584$ solutions for $n=11$.  (Unless I made a programming error.)

Comment: This is http://oeis.org/A176127: The number of permutations of {1,2,...,n,1,2,...,n} with the property that there are k numbers between the two k's in the set for k=1,...,n.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langford_pairing

Comment: In the "high-order" problem, you can't have $k$ numbers between each two $k$s; you may mean $k$ numbers between each $k$ and the next $k$.

Comment: Did you check the links and references at http://oeis.org/A014552 ?